# `sudo` to append to file with root permissions (inside `system(3)` from C)

Tags: shell, unix, sudo

I am attempting to use `sudo` to write to a file in `/etc` that is writable only by `root`, from inside an unprivileged C program.

```
system("sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo 'iface wlan0 inet dhcp' >> /etc/network/interfaces'");
```

This doesn't appear to fail, but the file is unmodified.  What is wrong?

Comment: Did you mean to tag `c` instead?

Comment: already tried but not working. i want to add line "iface wlan0 inet dhcp" to file interfaces in root directory

Comment: I've revised your question for you; this is much more of a shell question than a C question.  (Most importantly, most Unix C gurus do *not* think of the library function `system` when someone says "system call" -- that term is reserved for much lower-level operations.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structured as you have it, the redirection is evaluated *outside* the `sudo` operation, and therefore does not have root privileges and cannot open `/etc/network/interfaces` for writing.  You need to do it like this instead:

```
system("sudo /bin/sh -c \"echo 'iface wlan0 inet dhcp' >> /etc/network/interfaces\"");
```

so that the redirection is evaluated by the shell *inside* the sudo.

(Also, you can't nest single quotes inside single quotes.)

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, here is how I'd do that "the C way":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    const char string_to_append[] = "iface wlan0 inet dhcp\n";
    size_t string_size;
    FILE *fd;

    /* Check for permissions */
    if (getuid()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Run as root!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Now try to open the file for appending
     * NOTE: fopen() will fail anyway if you dont have enough
     * permissions to open this file with the specified mode,
     * so the above check calling getuid() is somewhat redundant
     */
    if ((fd = fopen("/etc/network/interfaces", "a")) == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Actual writing happens here */
    string_size = strlen(string_to_append);
    if (fwrite(string_to_append, sizeof(char), string_size, fd) != string_size) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```